# Insert the image sources one after another image

Tags: jquery, html

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zkvaoata/11/)

I want that whenever I click on any image, then that image src should go to image with the img1 id. If the img1 id has already an image, then the image source should go to the image having img2 id and so on.

```
$( ".img" ).click(function() {
  var newsrc=$( this ).attr("src");
    alert(newsrc);
    $( "#cropimage" ).attr("src",newsrc);
});
```

The HTML code is here.

```
<div id="img-container">
    <img id="cropimage" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="" id="img1" />
    <img src="" id="img2" />
    <img src="" id="img3" />
    <img src="" id="img4" />
    <img src="" id="img5" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add unique id to the container of the blank images.

`$("#myImages img[src='']")` will select all the images inside `#myImages` elements those are having `src` attribute value as blank. `first()` will get the first from the selected elements.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zkvaoata/12/)

```js
$(".img").on('click', function() {
  var newsrc = $(this).attr("src");
  $("#myImages img[src='']").first().attr("src", newsrc);
});
```

```css
#myImages img {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="img" src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png" />
<br/>
<img class="img" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/icons/hpcg/ribbon-black_68.png" />
<div id="img-container">
  <img id="cropimage" />
</div>
<div id="myImages">
  <img src="" id="img1" />
  <img src="" id="img2" />
  <img src="" id="img3" />
  <img src="" id="img4" />
  <img src="" id="img5" />
</div>
```

If you don't want to change your HTML structure, Check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1wkLncau/)

Comment: what if I donot have directly the images under that div @Tushar

Comment: @Amanjot You can still do that, but that has chances to change the `src` of other images which are having `src` as blank. See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1wkLncau/)

Comment: Yeah, I understand this @Tushar

Comment: what i am trying to achieve in my project is that I have 5 divs and each div will have a image that will come by clicking some default images like in the jsfiddle above. At the end, i want to make these images draggable and if image 1 is dragged to image 3, then image 3 should go to place of image 1 automatically. which I had already done at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692961/make-div-draggable-in-a-particular-position. Now, my question is If I drag image 1 at image 2 place, will the src only change or the whole image tag will be replaced by the new one.

Comment: @Amanjot After dragging and dropping, whole element is interchanged, no need of changing `src` values

Comment: And if I delete one image from these 5 images, that are added at the end, then what will be the structure, will the images be shifted or I had to insert image at the same place from where It was deleted.

Comment: @Amanjot The images will be shifted, as all HTML elements take empty space by default unless you've added some styles.

Comment: Can u plz make me a demo where I drag images and can delete any one in between them and then get their source html. I had been searching on this but did not get the best answer.